# Can I save a cookie and use it on an other page?

Tags: javascript, cookies

[RESOLVED]
I have a little website stored at file:/// with multiple pages with a quiz in each pages. I need to save the results of the quiz in a cookie. When I am changing page, the cookie turn undefined and I don't know how to access the cookie of the previous page. How could I do that ? Is using a cookie the best idea ?

Thank you and have a great day.

Ben

On first page, I put the number 1 in a cookie. When I try to access it on the second page, the cookie is undefined. I would want it to have 1 in it.

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly (because of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)).

But you can:

1. Centralize all cookies (cookiepot.com)
2. When some body visits one of your "share cookie"-sites you redirect him to cookiepot.
3. Cookiepot redirects the user back with the information you need

This is how Google+Youtube, Stackoverflow+Stackexchange do it. There is no other way except when servers change the information directly with each other.

Comment: Wtf I just want to save an information and use it on the next page. Isn't there a simple solution to that ???

Comment: Should I maybe use a session instead of a cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** after the quesion owner edited the question, is was discovered that he used a local file.

local files cannot use cookies in most browsers. you can use SessionStorage instead.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

---

2 pages can use the same cookies as long as they are in the **same domain**.

for example, website.com/a.html and website.com/b.html can use the same cookies, but otherwebsite.com/c.html wouldn't be able to use that cookie.

are your two pages in the same website?

If they aren't, there it is possible to allow one website to use another website's cookies but I have a feeling that's not the case.

Comment: index is at website/index (where cookies are defined) and pages are in website/proofs (proofs is a directory).

Comment: is your website public?
can you send a link to it?

Comment: No, the website is local

Comment: This is just a little school project

Comment: wait,how do you open the website? using double click on the html file?
if so, cokies are impossible to use!

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that... I am sorry, I am a beginner. I will use a session to save the quiz score !

Comment: just edit your question to include that you are accessing the website through file:/// so the question won't remain without an accepted answer :)

Comment: edited my answer too, so you can accept it if you like

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can save a cookie (`document.cookie = 'testcookie=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';`) and use it on any other page as long as the pages are on the same domain. This is how you save a cookie on a form submit or any other trigger: 
https://codepen.io/hac/pen/oOKOOe